# Batch gives me Invalid Path for a drive

Tags: batch-file

So I have  some code:

```
set "sourceImage=%~dp0\Files\silhouette.png"
set "targetFolder=H:"
...
for /r "%targetFolder%" %%f in (*) do (
```

but when I run it, the

```
for /r "%targetFolder%" %%f in (*) do (
```

line gives the error "Invalid path". Why?

Also, this loop takes a long time. Could I make it so that it will run for only a certain amount of time?

Comment: The syntax of `for /r "%targetFolder%" %%f in (*) do (` is correct.  Did you `echo "%targetFolder%"` before the `for` statement to verify it is `H:`?  Are you sure the error isn't from code inside the `for` loop?

Comment: `for /r` enumerates files.  The more files you enumerate, the longer it takes.  There is no way to *limit* the time a `for` statement runs.  The only solution is to use faster hardware or reduce the number of files `for /r` has to enumerate...  Defragging the HDD will help keep the heads from thrashing as much.  So that may help some too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is fine but the path in the for command is most often used with an explicit path like `"H:\"` or `"H:\Folder\data"`